# How can you take care of Endianness reading from H5PY into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, endianness, h5py

I would like to introduce the description of this question by saying that I don't have any code that can reproduce the error that I have.  I can (hopefully) explain the issue in detail, however.

At my work, we deal with large amounts of data and it comes from a variety of sources.  Some of these sources use Big Endian and some use Small Endian.  All that data is parsed and stored into an h5 file.

The tools that I develop are utilizing Pandas dataframes to manipulate the data in a variety of ways.

Our H5 files are set up in a way that doesn't seem to work with Pandas' df.read_h5() function call regularly (the data is not always in a nice structure, even inside the h5 file).  We have different functions that handle all the scenarios that we've come across to pull the data from the h5 file.  Most of our data is stored inside the h5 file as numpy structured arrays or slices of structured arrays.

Essentially there are some issues with Pandas whenever I take the data and try to put it into a dataframe.  The error that gets thrown is "**ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler**".  I know how to fix this, just call a byteswap on the underlying numpy array before you put it into the dataframe.  This is how I'm currently handling this issue, but I was wondering if there was a way to read the data from h5py into the machines native endianness so that I don't have to worry about doing a byteswap.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You might explore the file(s) with `h5py`.  That's a little lower level interface, producing `numpy` arrays.  It may handle the endedness better, since numpy's can have either dtype `>f8` or `<f8`.  You can make a dataframe from one or more of the arrays.  This is just a guess, since I've never dealt with files like this.

Answer (score 0):

With `h5py`

```
In [1]: import h5py                                                             
In [2]: f = h5py.File('testendedness.h5','w')                                   
In [3]: f.create_dataset('less',data=np.arange(5.).astype('<f8'))               
Out[3]: <HDF5 dataset "less": shape (5,), type "<f8">
In [4]: f.create_dataset('greater',data=np.arange(5.).astype('>f8'))            
Out[4]: <HDF5 dataset "greater": shape (5,), type ">f8">
In [5]: f.flush()                                                               
In [6]: f.close()
```

and in shell

```
1409:~/mypy$ h5dump testendedness.h5
HDF5 "testendedness.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "greater" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64BE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 5 ) / ( 5 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
      }
   }
   DATASET "less" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 5 ) / ( 5 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
      }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a good way to create datasets within h5py with a particular endianness, however, the files that we have are not created by us.  Also, this will not reproduce the Big-Endian error mentioned in the OP.